# Can't get to second page on Amazon with Selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I am scraping Amazon site (product name, price, picture, etc.) and I want to go to the second page to scrape all of the info from it. I ran the code couple of times. The first time it worked all okey, but all of the other time that I ran it I got this error message:

[image: Error message]

Here is my code. The thing that is not working is on the bottom in variable second page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random
import time


URL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&crid=288NMI7Z5E2WR&sprefix=laptop%2Caps%2C572&ref=nb_sb_noss_1"

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
]

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 3))

web_page = driver.page_source
# driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'lxml')


image_boxes = soup.find_all("div", class_="s-product-image-container aok-relative s-text-center s-image-overlay-grey puis-image-overlay-grey s-padding-left-small s-padding-right-small puis-flex-expand-height puis puis-v25h6k2ialgxcx2aefs5gqn1u23")
boxes = soup.find_all("div", class_="puisg-col puisg-col-4-of-12 puisg-col-8-of-16 puisg-col-12-of-20 puisg-col-12-of-24 puis-list-col-right")

name_list = []
price_list = []
number_of_reviews_list = []
images_list = []

for box in boxes:
    name = box.find("span", class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal").getText()
    price = box.find("span", class_="a-offscreen").getText()
    number_of_reviews = box.find("span", class_="a-size-base s-underline-text").getText()

    name_list.append(name)
    price_list.append(price)
    number_of_reviews_list.append(number_of_reviews)

    
for image_box in image_boxes:
    images = image_box.find("img", class_="s-image").get('src')
    images_list.append(images)


second_page = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 's-pagination-item s-pagination-button')
second_page.click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: If You look at the page there is a get parameter: `&ref=sr_pg_2` you can change this from 2 to 20 to get the pages. There is also `https://pypi.org/project/scrape-amazon/`

Comment: @MortenB Yeah maybe I can do that even without selenium. Will try it.

Comment: @MortenB I did it this way and it works. I don't even need Selenium. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem only using beautiful soup (@MortenB gave me an idea to do this). Here is the code that scrapes the info from the first 20 pages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import concurrent.futures

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "Accept-Language": "hr-HR,hr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
}

def scrape_page(page_num):
    URL = f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&crid=288NMI7Z5E2WR&qid=1702226389&sprefix=laptop%2Caps%2C572&ref=sr_pg_{page_num}"
    
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
    web_page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'lxml')

    image_boxes = soup.find_all("div", class_="s-product-image-container aok-relative s-text-center s-image-overlay-grey puis-image-overlay-grey s-padding-left-small s-padding-right-small puis-flex-expand-height puis puis-v25h6k2ialgxcx2aefs5gqn1u23")
    boxes = soup.find_all("div", class_="puisg-col puisg-col-4-of-12 puisg-col-8-of-16 puisg-col-12-of-20 puisg-col-12-of-24 puis-list-col-right")

    local_name_list = []
    local_price_list = []
    local_number_of_reviews_list = []
    local_images_list = []

    for box in boxes:
        name = box.find("span", class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal").getText()
        price = box.find("span", class_="a-offscreen").getText()
        number_of_reviews = box.find("span", class_="a-size-base s-underline-text").getText()

        local_name_list.append(name)
        local_price_list.append(price)
        local_number_of_reviews_list.append(number_of_reviews)

    for image_box in image_boxes:
        images = image_box.find("img", class_="s-image").get('src')
        local_images_list.append(images)

    return local_name_list, local_price_list, local_number_of_reviews_list, local_images_list

# Variables to store aggregated results
name_list = []
price_list = []
number_of_reviews_list = []
images_list = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(scrape_page, range(1, 20))

for result in results:
    name_list.extend(result[0])
    price_list.extend(result[1])
    number_of_reviews_list.extend(result[2])
    images_list.extend(result[3])

# Output results
print(len(name_list))
print(len(price_list))
print(len(number_of_reviews_list))
print(len(images_list))
```